# Mobile Safari and iframe show/hide with youtube source

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, mobile

I am coding a web app in mobile Safari and I seem to be hung up on something that I think should be simple enough, though it is eluding me right now.

Essentially, I have an `iframe` with a `src` of a youtube video.  When someone taps on a point of interest it shows that video in a little modal.  It has a close button for closing as well.

This uses nothing more than jQuery's `show` and `hide` methods.  Literally:

```
$(".selector").on("click", function() {

    $(this).show();

});
```

and

```
$(".selector").on("click", function() {

    $(this).hide();

});
```

When the modal comes up, the user has to tap on the youtube video to play it.  All is well with that part.

The strange part comes into play when you close it and try to open it again.  The modal pops up, but the video is blank.  There is just a black screen but the video can be heard still playing.

I am guessing this has something to do with the additional `window` context that the `iframe` creates.  Maybe this is hiding something additional down in that particular tree?

When I test my mobile code on a desktop, it works fine and I have no issues.  Testing on the iPhone does not.

Any thoughts on this one??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, solved the issue but it's very strange.  Apparently this is a known issue in older desktop versions of Safari.  Here is the solution for anyone who runs into the problem down the road.

Set your iFrame like so:

```
<iframe id="myYTVideo" src="" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Notice no `src` attribute has been added.  When you're opening your modal with jQuery, do this:

```
$(".openButtonSelector").on("click", function() {
    $("#myYTVideo").show();
    $("#myYTVideo").attr("src", youryoutubesourcehere);
});
```

When you close it, do this:

```
$(".closeButtonSelector").on("click", function() {
    $("#myYTVideo").hide();
    $("#myYTVideo").attr("src", "");
});
```

Not the most glamorous solution, but it works.  Not sure why it messes up on subsequent calls.  I guess it must be a mobile Safari bug.